# Make contiguous region in kernel space

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, device-driver, mapping

I'm allocating memory by `alloc_page(GFP_USER)` and I have allocated more than one page.
I need to make that I will see it as contiguous region (I need to make from it buffer), so I want to revoke to it `*(vm_beg + off)`.

I know that is possible by `mmap` in user space but how I can do that in kernel space?

Answer (score 5):

If you need to allocate **virtually** contiguous memory, then you can use `vmalloc()` to do so (more info [here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-8-sect-4)). The actual physical memory might be scattered though, so if you are planning on using that buffer with some hardware block (e.g DMA, PCI bus) outside of your CPU MMU, then `vmalloc()` might not be your best bet.

You probably should use `kmalloc()` for most purposes (more info [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6930)). The difference is that `vmalloc()` will always modify the page tables to get you new memory (a bit like `mmap()` in userland). Another difference is that `kmalloc()` gives you **phisically** contiguous memory and is usually faster than `vmalloc()` which has to always modify the page tables.

A very good source of information on Linux memory is [Linux Device Drivers 3](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) (specifically Chapter 15 in your case), you will probably find the answer to most of your questions inside.